# freemarker nodename with colon

Tags: xml, freemarker

I am having an issue with getting node that has ":" in it. For example I have this xml:

```
<item>
   <title>Title</title>
   <description>Description</description>
   <content:encoded>Some content</content:encoded>
</item>
```

So i am using freemarker to extract nodes, when I have ${item.title} i get the value from it but when I have ${item.content} I get freemarker error. Previously, I've been using only "." as delimeter and "@" for accessing node attributes(for example item.@attributeName), but this time, I think because of ":" I am getting error. So my question is: How to get node value that has colon in node name? Tried to search internet and freemarker website but no luck so far. I would spent more time on research but it is time sensitive so I have to ask for your help guys. Any suggestions/hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The element doesn't have a colon in the name. The name is `encoded`. `content` is the namespace (defined with `xmlns:content=...` elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you, Quentin! so if I have xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" in the root element, how I can call it in fremarker? I added <#ftl ns_prefixes={"content":"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"}> into my template and tried this: ${item["content"].encoded}, it is still not working, maybe syntax is wrong? Will keep digging.....

Comment: I found a solution, you just need to have <#ftl ns_prefixes={"content":"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"}> and when you type ${item["content:encoded"]} it shows the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said before in the comments, in my case, you need to have ns_prefixes declared in your ftl file and use ${item.["content:encoded"]}. So it was namespace issue. Thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Colon is a (future) operator, so you either write `item["content:encoded"]`, or starting with 2.3.22 (will be out on 2015-03-01) `item.content\:encoded`.

Comment: hmm, i tried ${item.content\:encoded} as you noted but it doesnt seem to be working, thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: As I said, it requires 2.3.22, which isn't released yet. But when it will be, this answer will be useful for others. Or even for you if you are using 2.3.22-rc02.

Comment: Oh, i see...Must have missed that part. I will definitely use it as soon as it is available, it seems to be easier. Regards,